# How to redirect default website URL to custom URL in .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm sure this is simple and I just haven't understood something, but could someone explain how I can redirect my `myDomain.com/` or `localhost:12345/` URLs to something like `myDomain.com/lang/Controller/Index` or `localhost:12345/lang/Controller/Index?`

My routing in `Startup.cs` looks like this:

```cs
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "LocalizedDefault",
                    template: "{culture:culture}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); 
                    routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{*catchall}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "RedirectToDefaultLanguage", culture = "en" });
            });
```

For now, I have modified the `launchSettings.json` file to launch on the URL I want, but this type of solution isn't very flexible, and once I start using a server, I will be forced to redirect requests for `myDomain.com` anyway. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First modify routing definition:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "LocalizedDefault",
        template: "{culture:regex(^[a-zA-Z]{{2}}(?:-[a-zA-Z]{{2}})*$)}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
        );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "RedirectToDefaultLanguage" }
        );
});
```

You don't want a catchall route in order to avoid too many redirects. Please note I'm using regex constraint to make sure culture is in twoletters format (en, it, fr) or basic tagged names (en-US, it-IT, ...). If you want complete rfc4647 compliancy you need to change the regex in `^[A-Za-z]{1,8}(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})*$`, but I think it would be too much (unless you are planning to provide i-klingon website XD ).

Then the RedirectToDefaultLanguage action in HomeController:

```
public IActionResult RedirectToDefaultLanguage()
{
    var currentCulture = Request.RouteValues["culture"];
    var dest = Request.Path.Value == "/" ? "" : Request.Path.Value;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString.Value))
        dest += $"?{Request.QueryString}";
    if (currentCulture == null)
    {
        return RedirectPermanent($"/en{dest}");
    }
    return RedirectToActionPermanent($"{currentCulture}{dest}");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, this was a really dumb question. Just use the `[Route("")]` attribute on whatever controller action you want to get called on the default URL.